# getsockname() can assign port to struct addr_in?

Tags: c, networking

```
self._socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

// create addr
struct sockaddr_in addr;
bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_len = sizeof(addr);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(0);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

// bind socket
bind(self._socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

printf("befor getsockname()->%d\n", ntohs(addr.sin_port));
socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
getsockname(self._socket, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &len); // if i comment this func, the last printf() will print 0; if not, it will print a real in use udp port(and it is correct!)
printf("after getsockname()->%d\n", ntohs(addr.sin_port));
```

So, is that when assign htons(0) to a port, the local socket must use getsockname() to assign a available port to itself? Or anything else?
  I think this is maybe because i just bind 0 to sin_port which mean to assign a random port but has not assigned by system yet, so just call getsockname() to make system really assign a port.

Comment: As the name sais `gethostname()` is getting something, namely info about the socket passed in. Setting is applied to it's second argument: The members of a `struct sockaddr_XYZ` are set with values describing the socket passed in.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is that when assign htons(0) to a port, the local socket must use getsockname() to assign a available port to itself? Or anything else?

No, you must use `bind()` to assign a port to the socket. `getsockname()` tells you what port was assigned if you specified zero.

Comment: Yeah, what you said is what i supposed! but in this code when i commented getsockname(), the last printf() just printf 0 as the first printf()! I think this is maybe because i just bind 0 to sin_port which mean to assign a random port but has not assigned by system yet, so just call getsockname() to make system really assign a port

Comment: No. It doesn't do that. It is a getter, not a setter. bind() does that, or connect() if you haven't called bind().

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the `getsockname` function is to get the `sockaddr` for the local side of the socket. For IPv4 sockets, this is an object of type `sockaddr_in` and it contains both the IP address and port.